# Is Session secure in ASP.NET apps to define admin member?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, authentication, admin

I am going to create a website with asp.net 4.5
to define members role I want to create 3 table in SQL

1. member info
2. member roles
3. define roles name

so in code,  when user login and redirected with FormsAuthentication
I want to define somehow he is admin or not
what should I do? 
my idea is: I get user id and make a query to check what kind of role he has, then put the role in a session and make the restriction

would be nice if you guys give me your opinion
if it is not safe or I should use another way tell me
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should go for a custom RoleProvider in you case, if you implement it by creating a class by inheriting it from `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider`.

Using this you don't need to use session, and your decision making will be simple.

You can check an example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers)

Comment: so if i use System.Web.Security.RoleProvider , i dont need to create table 2 and 3 ?( refer to my main question )

Comment: Table will be required, that is to persist the information, role provider will help you to take decisions on your website based on roles.